# My current eeprom version is newer than the newest

Tags: pi4-eeprom

i don't understand, my My current eeprom version is newer than the newest. The screenshot:

[image]

```
cd /etc/default/ && cat rpi-eeprom-update

FIRMWARE_RELEASE_STATUS="default"
```

can you explain to me ?
(Last bullseyes 64 installed on pi4 8gb)
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you have been selected as a guinea pig by the Foundation ;)